# Using apache proxypass to direct to different servers based on path

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-18.04, proxypass

I have the following in my default site config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

        ProxyPass /test http://10.0.0.100:8080/test
        ProxyPassReverse /test http://10.0.0.100:8080/test

</VirtualHost>
```

I have different servers for different applications, but would like them to appear as if one site to the end user. Either of the proxypass definitions I have defined work as I would expect when used alone, but when both are uncommented like shown above, going to /test just tries to open 127.0.0.1/test

Am I making a mistake, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) "The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins."

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /test http://10.0.0.100:8080/test
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://10.0.0.100:8080/test

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Wow, that seems pretty obvious now, thanks for pointing this out! Worked like a charm.